# Topic payment, problema al recibir la notificacion de pago

Tags: mercadopago, app

Tengo este código en C#:

```
 if (topic.Equals("payment"))
 {
     Hashtable payment_info = mp.getPaymentInfo(Request["id"]);
     var idOrde = ((Hashtable)((Hashtable)payment_info["response"])["collection"])["merchant_order_id"].ToString();
     merchant_order_info = mp.get("/merchant_orders/" + idOrde, true);
 }
```

Con esto me llega el pago a mi cuenta de mercadopago, pero nunca me llega la notificacion a mi servidor. ¿Alguien me dice que puede estar pasando?

Comment: Configuraste la url de recepción de la IPN aqui ? https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/ipn-notifications

Comment: Esto hay que hacerlo desde siempre? yo no lo tengo configurado en la cuenta de MP, lo hago en la preference del payment. Las notificaciones me estan llegando pero sin topic ni ID.